# How to handle cache in request promise native

Tags: node.js, request-promise

Hi currently i'm facing an issue that while using request-promise-native npm cache is not cleared properly that why getting previous result back as a response.How to handle cache in options.

Here is my code,

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
var query="x="+"&y=";
var options={
url:"https://xxxxx/path/name?"+query;
};
return request.get(options).then(result => {
var output=JSON.parse(result);
console.log(output);
return Promise.resolve(output);
}).catch(error =>{console.log(error)});
```